# Query that finds the matching foreign key and returns matching results?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am learning Oracle SQL for school and I have a problem I don't know how to approach. I have a few tables, one is the Employees table, and one is the Job table. The employee table contains some information including names, address, job code etc. The job code is a foreign key to the Job table, which matches the job code to the job title. I am required to write a statement that returns the names of the cashiers, while assuming that I do not know the job code of the cashier position.

The only way I have thought of approaching this is searching the Job table for 'Cashier' and getting the Jobcode #, and then using that job code # to return the employees with that job code. I figured I would use a join once I have the job code, but I don't know how to do that initial part of "finding" the job code in the first place. Is there a way to do this all in 1 statement?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  That combines two tables.

Comment: **use a join** is exactly so that you DON'T have to know the job code. You join the two tables on the `job_code` column - now you have long rows, with each employee's name and address, but also all the information about their job from the `Job` table, while you still don't know even what `job_code` values exist in either table. Even so, with the join now made, you can filter (`where` clause) to select only the employees whose job **description** (in whatever column) is `'cashier'`. And then, you can select just employee name in `select`, or whatever you need.

Comment: @mathguy Ahh I didn't realize that is how the join works. I thought the join had to know the matching value of each table to return anything. thank you.

Comment: Going to a more advanced level: If you write the query like that (join the two tables, and have a `where` clause to select only cashiers), you may feel that's a lot of work for little gain - why not simply get the `job_code` for cashiers first, and only then "join" the tables. You could indeed write the query that way. Better yet: even if you write it in the order "join first, and then the `where` clause", the Oracle cost-based optimizer will rewrite the query for you so it does the `where` condition on the `Job` table first, and only then the join. You don't need to worry about it!

Comment: ... and of course you can first get the job code and then use that to get the names (even without writing it down anywhere!) I show how in the Answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collecting in an Answer some of the thoughts I shared through Comments:

The obvious solution is - join the two tables (no need to know the job codes for this) and then filter for cashiers in a `where` clause. Care should be taken with the capitalization of `cashier` - it should match what is stored in the table. (If the table says `Cashier` with capital C, then the `where` condition should also. There are workarounds, but this is the best option.)

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name
from   employee e join job j on e.job_code = j.job_code
where  j.job_name = 'cashier'
```

This seems like a lot of work: if we are only interested in cashiers, why do we fully join the two tables? What if the `job` table has many rows, will that not result in a lot of wasted work? We only need one row from that table!

That is **correct**. It may be better to write the query so that the filtering comes first and the join is done last. Something like:

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name
from   employee e join ( select job_code from job where job_name = 'cashier') j
                  on e.job_code = j.job_code
```

Luckily, even if we write the query in the first form, the cost-based optimizer (a fundamental component of the query parser/compiler) will transform it into the second form. If you are familiar with "Explain Plans" you can try it: write two queries similar to these ones, you will see that the Explain Plan is the same.

This is done with no intervention on the developer's part, and it allows us a little flexibility (I consider it "laziness" when it's in reference to myself).

Of course, the second form suggests that the query could also be written with no joins at all:

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name
from   employee
where  job_code = ( select job_code from job where job_name = 'cashier' )
```

This query uses a "scalar subquery" in the `where` clause - a subquery that is expected to produce exactly one row in one column.